# Creating window.postMessage() in GWT for cross-domain iframe messaging

Tags: gwt, iframe, cross-domain, gwt-rpc, postmessage

I am trying to communicate between parent window and IFrame(IFrame source being on different domain), which is not allowed directly since the Same Origin Policy. The communication is easy via window.postMessage() method of HTML5. So i searched for existing works in this field and i found [gwt-rpc-plus](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rpc-plus/) library
It includes a class [*PostMessageFrameTransportRequest*](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rpc-plus/source/browse/trunk/gwt-rpc-plus/gwt/com/dotspots/rpcplus/client/transport/impl/PostMessageFrameTransportRequest.java). Now, I think that this would work. But I am not getting on how to use this class. 
I need some help with this code and if anyone knows about some other method to give same behavior as window.postMessage() please help me out.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can just use JSNI to call javascript directly

something like:

```
private native void sendMessage(String message)/*-{
    $wnd.postMessage(...., message);
}-*/;
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to avoid HTML 5 codes since it is currently not supported by all browsers. Now according to my analysis, http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rpc-plus/source/browse/trunk/gwt-rpc-plus/gwt/com/dotspots/rpcplus/client/transport/impl/PostMessageFrameTransportRequest.java class uses a form to send data to the child IFrame and it works fine but i have to include an event handler on the child source. I dont want that. So it would be great help if you can go through this code once and tell me about how to use it.